# Where do NPM audit warnings come from?

Tags: security, npm, npm-audit

From what I can glean from [the docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/audit),

> The audit command submits a description of the dependencies configured in your project to your default registry and asks for a report of known vulnerabilities.

So there is an NPM registry out there, I assume the same one from which I am going to get packages with `npm install`, and along with the packages it contains security audit warnings. If so, how does one register these warnings?

Comment: Did you read https://docs.npmjs.com/reporting-a-vulnerability-in-an-npm-package? There's also a security policy: https://www.npmjs.com/policies/security. If you're using a different repository for your installs, look for their equivalent.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, that's what I was looking for, thanks.  If you go ahead and make it an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default repository for NPM installs is https://www.npmjs.com. They have a [security policy](https://www.npmjs.com/policies/security), along with a specific [guide to reporting](https://docs.npmjs.com/reporting-a-vulnerability-in-an-npm-package) that states:

> If you find a security vulnerability in an npm package (either yours
>   or someone else’s), you can report it to the npm Security team to help
>   keep the Javascript ecosystem safe.
>
> ...
>
> 2. On the package page, click **Report a vulnerability**.